# Executing a jar on mac 10.8

Tags: java, macos, jar, execute, double-click

Although this seems like a rather obvious question, I couldn't find the answer anywhere online.

After I create the jar file, I can run it successfully using the command line by saying

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

However, I want this file to be a bit more user-friendly, in other words, run on double click. For some reason when I double click the jar file the mac jar launcher (Jar\ Launcher.app) opens, pauses one second then closes. I appreciate the help.

Ps. I have made jar files through the command line, bluej, and eclipse, none of these ways solved the issue.

Comment: Does your JAR reference resource files, such as images?  Perhaps when you double-click it the working directory is in a different location.  Also you may want to try opening /Applications/Utilities/Console -- there may be an error message there.

Answer (score 14):

I would create a shell script to enclose it in terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar yourjarfile.jar
read -p 'Hit [Enter] to continue...'
```

I added pause, but unless your java application is immediately reaching termination, it shouldn't be necessary (you can stop the shell script after the "java" line).

Comment: Hi, Rogue. Thanks for the advice. Right now I have a temporary file (a .command file that runs my jar file on double click).

Comment: Nice, I believe you can add the "read -p" as well to pause it in .command, which will let you see runtime errors.

Answer (score 2):

There is a program on OS X called [`Jar Bundler`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Jar_Bundler/Introduction/Introduction.html) that comes with your install of Xcode developer tools. You can use this to convert .jar files to native Mac OS X .app executables.

Comment: I am aware of the Jar Bundler application, I forgot to mention it but that didn't solve my issue, thanks though.

Comment: It seems like exactly what you want, but no worries.

Comment: Jar Bundler is long since deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, the jar bundler did the same thing as the jar launcher, it opened, paused a second then exited.

Answer (score 1):

You need [Java WebStart](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/), snippet from the link `Java Web Start software provides the power to launch full-featured applications with a single click. Users can download and launch applications, such as a complete spreadsheet program or an Internet chat client, without going through lengthy installation procedures`