# Let jar file run in cmd or terminal on mac

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd

The program I write in Eclipse runs on console purely. I hope to export it to a jar file then use launch4j make it an executable .exe file. The program should desirably be opened in cmd or terminal on Mac once clicked. But it seems I can't open it with cmd and unless I used swing or awt, nothing to show when I clicked either jar file or exe file. So what is the problem and how should I do to make it runnable on cmd!
**PS:I dont want to type any command line, just click the jar file or exe file and it started to run on cmd or terminal!**

Answer (score 1):

You would possibly try script files for this task:

**windows: run.bat**

```
java -jar your.jar
```

**mac: run.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar your.jar
```

Comment: Thank you it works on Windows now. But what if I converted it to an exe file, how should I run?

Answer (score 0):

This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18858419) shows the use of [Jar Bundler](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Jar_Bundler/Introduction/Introduction.html) to convert jar to executable native Mac OS X .app executables

I think you can give it a try. Enjoy!

**Edit**

[Jar2Exe](http://www.jar2exe.com/) seems promising to convert jar file to executable for Windows and Linux Platform.

You can try them and let me know too if that work for you.

Comment: It works with jar file now, but not with exe file. I double clicked and there is nothing to show with exe

Comment: @Zoe I have updated my answer , check if that works for you (if you're still looking for an answer ;))

Answer (score 0):

launch4j could work on windows/osx/linux, but I think you need a mac to build the executable file. And the jar file itself can be run when double-clicked, if you specify the Main Class in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  file, like this:

```
Main-Class: com.xxx.xxx.YourClass
```

After this, the jar file could be double-clicked to run.

Comment: When you export jar file from Eclipse, you can specify the Main Class, so you need not edit the manifest file manually.