# How to find out what happens when I double-click .jar file on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, jar, aem

There is a .jar file that runs AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) Author instance once I double-click it. I wanted to run it from command line `java -jar cq-author-p4502.jar`, but it does something differently than when I double-click it. It serves me a web page for product registration.

So, I assume that double-clicking `cq-author-p4502.jar` doesn't do the same thing as `java -jar cq-author-p4502.jar`. Where could I find out what is being executed on double-click on .jar file on Mac?

Comment: Look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858363/executing-a-jar-on-mac-10-8) post.

Comment: Is the `license.properties` file available in the same folder as the jar file. If so, it shouldn't redirect you to product registration page.

Comment: Yes, the `license.properties` file is in the same folder as the `.jar` file. There happens to be difference if I run it from the actual directory in comparison to when I run it from another directory. When I run it from the actual directory everything is fine. However, when I run it from elsewhere it shows me this page for product registration. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Finder, right click the jar file and select Open With, then take a good look at what is selected as the default application. On El Capitan the default is `Jar Launcher.app`

On OSX there is a command line tool called `open` which does almost the same thing as double clicking in Finder. Perhaps the way to get the behavior you want from the command line is this.

```
open cq-author-p4502.jar -a "/System/Library/CoreServices/Jar Launcher.app"
```

Comment: This is a way to run this file with no problem from elsewhere on the system, not only from the actual directory where the file is contained. Thanks.