# How to execute Carrot2 Document Clustering server

Tags: java, carrot2

I downloaded the Carrot2 Document clustering server build 3.15.0 for Mac. The read me file says:

> The DCS requires a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7.0 or later. To
>   run the DCS, execute the 'dcs' script and point your browser at
>   http://localhost:8080 for further instructions.

Mac OS Sierra doesn't make it easy, but I got 1.8.0_112 installed.

The problem is that I don't know how to execute the 'dcs' script.

There are .cmd, .sh, .war, and .jar files. I wasn't sure which of those to work with. I thought **.jar** looked promising, so I followed some of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858363/executing-a-jar-on-mac-10-8) and tried this in a terminal window:

```
java -jar invoker.jar
```

I cd-ed to the correct directory, but it just says `Provide main class`, but I'm not sure what or where that is.

Can anybody provide instructions or a link to how to do this?

Comment: Normally you should use the scripts to launch the DCS -- does the .sh script work for you?

Comment: I'm away from my home computer today, but will try that later tonight. Do I just change to the directory and type 'dcs.sh' or is there an exec, run, java, or ...?

Comment: I found sh dcs.sh and it works. Thanks! If you post that as an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `dcs.sh` (on Linux/Mac) and `dcs.cmd` (on Windows) to start the server. The scripts will set some extra options for the JVM and then start the DCS. In case of any problems, append the `-v` option to see diagnostic output.